# C - Writing directly to an array in while loop while receiving data with recv

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, recv

Here is my code:

```
FILE *responseStorage = fopen("response", "w");

if(responseStorage == NULL){
    //error handling
}

int receivedTotal = 0;
while(1){
    ssize_t received = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZ, 0);
    if( received == -1 ){
        //error handling
    }
    if( received == 0 ){
        //end of stream
        break;
    }
    receivedTotal += received;
    if(fwrite(buf, received, 1, responseStorage) != 1){
         //error handling
    }
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
}

fclose(responseStorage);

FILE *responseFile = fopen("response", "r");
char responseArray[receivedTotal];
if(fread(responseArray, receivedTotal, 1, responseFile) == 0){
   //error
}
```

I am calling a `ssize_t received = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZ, 0);`, recieving data from server, saving how much data I received in `receivedTotal += received;` and writing that data to with `fwrite(buf, received, 1, responseStorage)` to my file `FILE *responseStorage`. After that at the end of the stream loop breaks and I open `responseStorage` file in `r` mode, make an array of the size `receivedTotal`, `char responseArray[receivedTotal];`, and with `fread(responseArray, receivedTotal, 1, responseFile` write that data from `responeStorage` file to `responseArray`.

Is there a way to write dirrectly to a `responseArray`? I have to validate response later on so I need it in an array. I know I would have to dynamically alocate the space for array with `malloc`. I want to avoid using `receivedTotal` and `responseStorage`.

Comment: Dynamically allocate `responseArray` with `malloc()`, and grow it with `realloc()` as necessary.

Comment: Note that the buffer memset is just a waste of cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already reading from your socket into `buf`, so all you have to do is write `buf` to a dynamically allocated string rather than `responseStorage`.  Like you say you just have ti handle memory space to fit your response.

The inefficient but really easy way to do this is to reallocate storage every time you read.   You can allocate storage for the sum of the previous response reads and the new string in `buf`,  then write both strings to newly allocated space.   You know the sum of the length of these strings +1 for the null byte, so you don't have to worry much about available allocated space.  This is however pretty expensive because the reads get copied over and over again.

The slightly more complex way to do it would be to allocate one probably fairly large main response string buffer,  keep track of its length total allocated space and use `strncat` to continue to concatenate `buf` until it's length exceeds the remaining space in response,  +1 (for terminating nil byte).  When there's not enough room,  you can call `realloc` to obtain more memory. `realloc` is not very effficient (by C standards) because it is likely to need to allocate different space, copy existing data, and then return a new pointer.

if you wanted to be really clever,  you could allocate one big buffer,  and send `read` a pointer at the offset of the next available spot in buffer.   You still might need to grow buffer but at least you don't need to copy it.   `buf` then becomes your response array.  This is the implementation I'll demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  size_t size = 2;
  size_t len  = 0;
  char* fullbuf = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
  while(1) {
    ssize_t b = read(STDIN_FILENO, fullbuf + len, sizeof(char) * (size - len-1) );
    if( b < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't read from stdin: ");
      exit(2);
    } else if( b == 0 ){
      break;
    }
    if( b + len + 1 >= size) {
      // time to allocate more memory
      size = size * 2;
      fullbuf = realloc(fullbuf, sizeof(char) * size);
      if( fullbuf == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate %zd more bytes of memory\n", size);
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    len += b;
  }
  fullbuf[len] = '\0'; //terminating null space
  printf("%s", fullbuf);
}
```

For this demonstration I read from stdin instead of a socket, but same idea.  I read only as much data as is available in `buf`.  When it's full (but the terminating byte), I double its space.  Note that I set `fullbuf` to the output of realloc - it may be the same address, it may not.

To prove it works, I started at the rather insane 2 byte buffer, and double from there so there's lots of `realloc` calls.  I grabbed 32k of lorem ipsum to use as input.

```
$ du -h file.txt
 32K    file.txt
$ shasum -a 256 file.txt
346f2adbd1fdca6bf3b03fb0a4d2fd0030e3363e9a9c5d1e22747e1bcc316e37  file.txt
$ ./t  < file.txt | shasum -a 256
346f2adbd1fdca6bf3b03fb0a4d2fd0030e3363e9a9c5d1e22747e1bcc316e37  -
```

Awesome, if the shasums are the same, that means I outputted `file.txt` exactly.

Comment: Use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`

Comment: @DanielFarrel I have managed to do something myself reading your first response. I have defind a CHUNK 4096 and used it in definde a `size_t csize = CHUNK` and to allocate memory in `responseArray = malloc (CHUNK)`.

I then check in my while loop if `(csize == strlen(buf))` and allocate memory in response if that is true I increment `csize +=  CHUNK` and reallocate the size of `responseArray` with `responseArray = realloc(responseArray, csize);`. If there is still space left I just `strcpy(responseArray, buf)`. Is this effecient enough or is there a case I will have a problem?

Comment: you should be using `strncat`, not `strcpy` or `strncpy`.  (Always use the `n` size-limited versions as the others cause buffer overflow vunlerabilities, and only you know the allocated size).  strcpy is going to copy `buf` to `responseArray`.   You want to _concatenate_ (append) `buf` to `responseArray`.   `str*()` are string functions and often expect a trailing newline, but your streamed data won't have one, so be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, most efficient way is to use VirtualAlloc, reserving a very large chunk and committing initially one page (4096 bytes). If BUFSIZ is larger, commit more pages to make it fit. Assign the address to responsiveArray. Read the first packet in there. For the next recv calls, keep committing extra pages and adjust the recv buffer address, making sure, that there is least BUFSIZ free bytes available. You will have continuous address space, no fragmentation, no hogging extra memory, no rewriting, and no writing to disk.